# Warning: Dependant package with key emulator not found! - VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies, android-sdk-build-tools

I am running flutter on VScode and when I try downloading `Buildtools` or `System-images` through commandline, it gives this warning :

```
Warning: Dependant package with key emulator not found!

Warning: Unable to compute a complete list of dependencies.
```

[image]